# Ms Excel VBA Select All or (Ctrl + A) Code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This is my sample data.

[image]

And this is the VBA code produced with macro when I selecting all (ctrl + A) inside `A1:C3`, then change the table format.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:C3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$C$3"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"
End Sub
```

Output

[image]

The problem started when I have more data, let say bigger range `A1:C4`.

[image]

The code above won't select all, instead it selects only `A1:C3`.

[image]

Last row `A4:C4` won't be affected with this code.

How do I change this doesn't matter how big the table is?

Comment: I don't have time to write out an answer right now, but basically create a dynamic range, use this instead of `"A1:C3"`, see this link for named ranges https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For the equivalent of `Ctrl + A` go down to the `CurrentRegion` section*

**UsedRange** - All cells (with values)

The simplest change you can do to your code to include everything is changing `Range("$A$1:$C$3")` to `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`.
Note that this will make a table to include **everything** in the sheet, so if you have other data in there, you need a different approach. If you want everything included, then great, you can trim some of the code away if you like:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ActiveSheet.UsedRange, , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"
End Sub
```

**CurrentRegion** - All connected cells (with values)

If you want a more constrained way of doing it, you can use `CurrentRegion` instead.
If you know that the table will always be including for example `A1` then you could use `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` instead:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table1"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"
```

If location is not a given, you could even select a cell before running it, and use `Selection.CurrentRegion` instead.

[image]

Example run with the following code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Set objListObject = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection.CurrentRegion, TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9")
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @Christofer Weber. This is the answer that I'm looking for. I've been searching for tons of article, your code is the most easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, you only select and assign only the data in the A1:C3 range.

```
Range("A1:C3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$C$3"), , xlYes).Name = _
"Table1"
```

There's no way to change the code at any time based on your dynamic range, this time you need to include the A4:C4 range, but next time you might include A5:C5, the code won't adapt.

What you need to do is change it manually every time you change the range, change the parameters in the above two paragraphs, for example, you need to include A4:C4, then the corresponding two paragraphs of A1:C3 need to be changed to A1:C4：

```
Range("A1:C4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$C$4"), , xlYes).Name = _
"Table1"
```

Comment: going in and changing vba every time the parameters change defeats the point of using vba